# Highlight buttons on screen

Tags: ios

im trying to stand out buttons in my screen, i want to change their background image, wait few seconds, restore background image and same with next button.

I´ve wrote this code:

```
-(void)animateButtons
{
    UILabel * lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, scroll.frame.origin.y-20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 20)];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    for(int c=0;c<arr.count&&animationRunning;c++)
    {
        MenuItem * m = [arr objectAtIndex:c];
        [lbl setText:m.name];
        MyButton * b = (MyButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:c+1];
        NSMutableString * str = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:m.image];
        [str appendString:@"_focused.png"];
        [b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        sleep(2.5);
        str = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:m.image];
        [str appendString:@"_normal.png"];
        [b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if(c==arr.count-1)
        {
            animationRunning=false;
        }
    }
}
```

that method its called in this way, so it doesnt block UI thread.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(animateButtons) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

But it just change first button background and then nothing.

Using NSLog i can see that the method is still running but no changes on Buttons.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Changes to the UI need to be made on the main thread. If made on any other thread they will render unpredictable results. You can use timer  to do the same thing.

Comment: Did either answer help you? If so, mark it as the accepted answer or upvote if it was helpful but wasn't quite the right answer. This will help you build reputation, and encourage others to answer your questions. Otherwise, you could comment on the answers or your question to get more clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change UI properties from a background thread, this leads to all kinds of problems including crashes. To keep your original algorithm you could dispatch the UI update back to the main thread. But this is not a very efficient use of threads, just use a simple NSTimer that runs on the main thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, perform all of your UI changes on the main thread. Here's an option for accomplishing what you're trying to do, no NSTimer required.

```
-(void)animateButtons
{
    for (...)
    {
        // set focused state
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(restoreButtons) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];
}

-(void)restoreButtons
{
    for (...)
    {
        // set normal state
    }
}
```